# I want to remove the repeated addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I working on the concept in PHP code. while selecting the drop down box . I append the textbox. I want to remove the repeated values and vice versa

```
$package=array("Sliver","Gold","Broze","Limited","Unlimited","Constants");
```

```
<select id="choose_package" >
<?php foreach ($package as $packagevalue) {?>
    <option value="<?php echo $packagevalue;?>"> <?php echo $packagevalue;?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
<div class="package_limit"></div>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#choose_package").on("change", function () {
        var selectval=$("#choose_package").val();
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(selectval));
        $(".package_limit").append(div);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });
});

function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return '<input name = "package_name_'+ value +'" readonly type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
    '<input name = "package_price_'+ value +'" type="text" value = "" />&nbsp;'+
    '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JVRK/w7xfzdus/13/

Comment: can you please explain your query a bit

Comment: sure abhi  i can able to 2 "sliver" and its should append 2 sliver input textbox. but my query was if i selected sliver and sliver value should be remove from select box and if you remove the textbox means the value should value visible in select box

Comment: if i understand your question well then please find my ans, else let me know if you want anything else

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mvwns78h/

```
var arr = new Array(); 
$("#choose_package").on("change", function () {
    var selectval=$("#choose_package").val();
    if($.inArray(selectval, arr) == -1) { // check if selected value is not in array then only append
       var div = $("<div />");
       div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(selectval));
       $(".package_limit").append(div);
       arr.push(selectval); // push selected value in array
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Before to append the new div, check if the new element has been already created:

```
if ($('input[name="package_name_' + selectval + '"]').length == 0) {
  $(".package_limit").append(div);
}
```

My snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#choose_package").on("change", function () {
    var selectval=$("#choose_package").val();
    var div = $("<div />");
    div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(selectval));
    if ($('input[name="package_name_' + selectval + '"]').length == 0) {
      $(".package_limit").append(div);
    }
  });
  $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
    $(this).closest("div").remove();
  });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
  return '<input name = "package_name_'+ value +'" readonly type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
    '<input name = "package_price_'+ value +'" type="text" value = "" />&nbsp;'+
    '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<select id="choose_package" >
    <option value="Sliver"> Sliver</option>
    <option value="Gold"> Gold</option>
    <option value="Broze"> Broze</option>
    <option value="Limited"> Limited</option>
</select>
<div class="package_limit">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand the query well then here is your solution 
https://jsfiddle.net/abhiyx/w7xfzdus/16/

Please find my Code

```
            <select id="choose_package" >
                    <option value="Sliver"> Sliver</option>
                    <option value="Gold"> Gold</option>
                    <option value="Broze"> Broze</option>
                    <option value="Limited"> Limited</option>
            </select>
            <div class="package_limit">
            </div>
```

and jquery part

```
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
        $("#choose_package").on("change", function () {
            var selectval=$("#choose_package").val();
          var div = $("<div />");
                   div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(selectval));
           $("#choose_package option[value='"+selectval +"']").remove();
                    $(".package_limit").append(div);
                });
                $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $("#choose_package").append('<option value="'+ this.id+'">'+this.id+'</option>');
                    $(this).closest("div").remove();
                });
            });
        function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
                return '<input name = "package_name_'+ value +'" readonly type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
                       '<input name = "package_price_'+ value +'" type="text" value = "" />&nbsp;'+
                         '<input type="button" id= "'+ value+'" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
            }
            </script>
```

Comment: but first option is never able to add at all. if that also works means it would be great

Comment: there is a way out if you can add <option value=""> </option>

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML part

```
<select id="choose_package" >
   <option value="None">-- Select --</option>
   <option value="Sliver"> Sliver</option>
   <option value="Gold"> Gold</option>
   <option value="Broze"> Broze</option>
   <option value="Limited"> Limited</option>
</select>
<div class="package_limit"></div>
```

JQuery Part

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
        $("#choose_package").on("change", function () {           
           var selectval=$(this).find('option:selected').val();
          var div = $("<div />");
                   div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(selectval));               
           $("#choose_package option[value='"+selectval +"']").attr("disabled", true);
                    $(".package_limit").append(div);
            $(this).val('None');
                });
                $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {          
       $("#choose_package option[value='"+ this.id+"']").attr("disabled", false);
                    $(this).closest("div").remove();
                });
            });
        function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
                return '<input name = "package_name_'+ value +'" readonly type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
                       '<input name = "package_price_'+ value +'" type="text" value = "" />&nbsp;'+
                         '<input type="button" id= "'+ value+'" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
            }
            </script>
```